# Reference not returning?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

My class has an array of objects, call it `Foo`. It is stored as `Foo* m_Foos` in the class. Say it has a value at [0], guaranteed, and `Foo` has a property called `IsSet`that's just a bool or something.

```
void TryThis()
{
   Foo returnValue;
   GetValue(returnValue);
   returnValue.IsSet = true;
   if(m_Foo[0].IsSet != returnValue.IsSet)
   {
      // ERROR!!!!
   }
}

void GetValue(Foo &container)
{
   container = m_Foos[0];
}
```

Can anyone explain why m_Foo[0] =/= returnValue? Where is the error in my syntax?

I expect m_Foo[0] to be the same reference as returnValue, the same `Foo` in memory.

Comment: `GetValue()` assigns the value of `returnValue` to be equal to the value of `m_Foos[0]`.   It doesn't cause `returnValue` to be a reference to `m_Foos[0]`.

Comment: I updated the question to have an example. The code now has a conditional

Comment: Not sure how else you'd like it rephrased. I got an answer, so that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `TryThis()` is not modifying the `Foo` object that is stored in the `m_Foos` array.

`GetValue()` is assigning the `Foo` object from `m_Foos[0]` to another `Foo` object that is local to `TryThis()`.  A *copy* is being made during that assigment.  `TryThis()` is then modifying the copy, not the original.

If you want `TryThis()` to modify the original `Foo` object directly, you need to do something more like this instead:

```
void TryThis()
{
   Foo &returnValue = GetValue();
   returnValue.IsSet = true;
   // m_Foo[0] is set true.
}

Foo& GetValue()
{
   return m_Foos[0];
}
```

Or this:

```
void TryThis()
{
   Foo *returnValue;
   GetValue(returnValue);
   returnValue->IsSet = true;
   // m_Foo[0] is set true.
}

void GetValue(Foo* &container)
{
   container = &m_Foos[0];
}
```

Comment: Ah so I needed a pointer in the `TryThis`, I can't just make it local? Thank you.

Comment: @user99999991, that is not a pointer. It's a reference.

Comment: I meant the second example, that has a pointer. More in line with my original example's format with a void function. My mistake.

Comment: `TryThis()` needs to use a reference/pointer to `m_Foos[0]`, not a copy of it.